# Problemas jQuery dados

Tags: jquery, html

Estou tendo um pequeno problema no meu codigo jquery, eu queria fazer um soma em que eu coloco o valor no input + o valor span em uma div e gerar isso em um outro span, porém ele não me mostra resultados.

HTML

```
<div class="media-body">
<div class="menu-tittle">

</div>
<div class="quantity">
  <form action="#">
    <div class="pizza-add-sub">
      <input type="text"  class="qtdpedidos" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="pizza-price"> <span class="pizza">10.00</span>
</div>
```

Valor do Pedido: R$0.00

JQUERY

```
 $("#somar").click(function(){
  var total = 0;
  var valor= $('.pizza').val());

  $('.qtdpedidos').each(function(){
    var valor = Number($(this).val());
    if (!isNaN(valor)) total += valor;
  });

  total = total - desconto;
  $(".resultado").html(total.toFixed(2));
});
```

Agradeço desde já

estou testando aqui https://jsfiddle.net/bx3c5trg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um snippet com uma *alternativa* de solução, nota que estava dando um erro pois no teu código

```
var valor= $('.pizza').val());
```

está com um parenteses a mais, outra coisa é a variável `desconto` que não foi declarada em lugar nenhum. Espero que ajude.

```js
$("#somar").click(function() {
  var total = 0;
  var valorPizza = $('.pizza').text().substring(0, $('.pizza').text().indexOf('.'));
  //console.log(valorPizza);

  $('.qtdpedidos').each(function() {
    var valorInput = parseInt($(this).val());
    //if (!isNaN(valor)) total += valor;
    total = parseInt(valorPizza) + parseInt(valorInput);
  });

  //total = total - desconto;
  $(".resultado").html(total.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="media-body">
  <div class="menu-tittle">

  </div>
  <div class="quantity">
    <form action="#">
      <div class="pizza-add-sub">
        <input type="text" class="qtdpedidos" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="pizza-price"> <span class="pizza">10.00</span>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="SOMAR" id="somar" /> Valor do Pedido: R$<span class="resultado">0.00</span>
```

Comment: Resolveu sim, obrigado matias!!n